# I am writing a windows forms app in VB.Net to open Excel worksheets but I can't get the references/import statement to work

Tags: vb.net, excel, reference

I am writing a windows forms app in VB.Net to open Excel worksheets but I can't get the references/import statement to work. I have seen some working code which has the reference Microsoft.Office.Core but I am unable to add this reference. I just want to get the squiggly lie out from under my 'Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop'statement. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this .. (sample on VS2005 and Excel 11)

1. On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
2. On the COM tab, locate Microsoft Excel Object Library, and then click Select. In Visual Studio 2005, locate Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library on the COM tab.
3. Click OK in the Add References dialog box to accept your selections. If you are prompted to generate wrappers for the libraries that you selected, click “Yes”.

Further info .. http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must click Build > Add Reference > COM > Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Then `Import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`